# plot using few values of a Specific column in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a column named city which is having more than 10 different cities and that values are scattered throught out 10000 rows. Now I want to draw some exploratory analysis based on specific cities among 10 cities.
I wrote currently-

```
ggplot(irdata,aes(x=City))+geom_histogram(binwidth=5)

ggplot(irdata, aes(x = City,y=50, fill = Section)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + coord_flip()
```

In both of the plotting I am using all the cities which I don't want. How to plot using some specific city like

```
ggplot(irdata,aes(x=City=='Dublin'))+geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

But the above piece of the code anyway won't work as it will bring the result with logical output/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(irdata[irdata$City=='Dublin',],aes(x=City))+geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

Comment: what If I have more than 1 city to test like Dublin , Cork , London .. like that

Comment: Use irdata[irdata$City %in% c("Dublin","Cork","London"),]

Answer (score 1):

What about just subsetting the data?

```
ggplot(subset(irdata, City == "Dublin"),aes(x=City))+geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

Comment: what If I have more than 1 city to test like Dublin , Cork , London .. like that

Answer (score 1):

this should be a comment as it is basically the same as the other answers (except “City %in% ..), but I am not allowed to delete it :-(

```
ggplot(subset(irdata, City %in% c("Dublin","Cork","London")), aes(x=City)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```